# Server stuck in reading the buffer Java

Tags: java, tcp, server

I have a problem with a multi-connected server TCP. It accepts connection to client, but it stuck when it must read data (array of bytes[]) in `InputBuffer`.

The code is follow:

**Server:**

```
public class thread_acc extends Thread{

private final ServerSocket sock_acc;  
public thread_acc() throws IOException {
    this.sock_acc = new ServerSocket(10000);
}
@Override
public void run(){
    for(;;){
        try {
            Socket sock_client = sock_acc.accept();
            System.out.println("connection accepts");
            new Thread(new thread_proc(sock_client)).start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {               Logger.getLogger(thread_acc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }      
    }
  }
}

public class thread_proc implements Runnable{
private Socket sock_client;
public thread_proc(Socket sock){
    this.sock_client = sock;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        procRequest();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(thread_proc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(thread_proc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
} 
void procRequest() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
byte[] pack1 = socket.readSocket(sock_client);
System.out.println("read pack 1");
byte[] pack2 = socket.readSocket(sock_client);
System.out.println("read pack 2");
.....
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class thread_key implements Runnable {
private static InetAddress IpServer = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
private static int PortServer = 10000;
private Socket sock_send;
private int id;
private String namefile;

public thread_key(int id, String namefile) throws IOException {
    this.sock_send = new Socket(IpServer, PortServer);
    this.id = id;
    this.namefile = namefile;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    Request();
}

private String[] Request(int iddoc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ...generations Keys RSA and payloads....

    byte[] pack1 = RSA.encryptPub(payload1, pub);
    byte[] pack2 = RSA.encryptPub(payload2, pub);
    socket.writeSocket(sock_send, pack1);
    socket.writeSocket(sock_send, pack2);
    System.out.println("write ok");

    }
}
```

**Read and Write:**

```
public class socket {

public static void writeSocket(Socket sock, byte[] pacchetto) throws IOException{
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    out.writeObject(pacchetto);
    out.flush();
}

public static byte[] readSocket(Socket sock) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    byte[] pacchetto = (byte[]) in.readObject();
    return pacchetto;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want help with your code, make it readable. Follow formatting and naming conventions - I use the [Google style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html). Classes should be named like `ThisExample` - variables should look like `thisExample`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create new object streams every time you want to send or receive something. Use the same streams for the life  of the socket, at both ends. Object streams have headers which are read or written on construction, so if construction at the receiver doesn't match construction at the sender, errors will ensue.

Comment: This solution is the first that i had adopted but it created same problems.

Comment: i solve with a sleep in a client, because while client write into a buffer server is creating thread with buffer

Comment: Sleeps in network code are just literally a waste of time. You need to create the `ObjectOutputStream` before the `ObjectInputStream.`